# Запятая перед количеством

Tags: пунктуация

Дополнительная плата за сбор партии(,) количеством менее 10 посылок(,) не взимается.

Запятые перед *количеством* и перед *не* ставятся или нет?

Comment: Предложение необходимо перестроить: "партия количеством" - некорретное словосочетание (это _посылки_ могут быть отправлены "количеством"). Возможные варианты: "партия посылок в количестве (столько-то) штук", "партия размером в столько-то посылок".

Comment: "Партия посылок в количестве (столько-то) штук" — тоже не совсем верно, партия-то одна, а не в количестве. То, что "количество" относится к "посылкам", а не к "партии", становится понятно далеко не сразу.

Answer (score 1):

1. Правильно: ***Дополнительная плата за сбор партии количеством менее 10 посылок не взимается.***

В данном случае не обособляется несогласованное определение, выраженное падежной формой существительного.

Определение стоит в нормальной позиции (после определяемого слова) и обозначает **отличительный** признак предмета.

Для сравнения: *Небольшие партии, количеством менее 10 посылок, уже подготовлены к отправке.* Здесь указан уточняющий признак.

Правило: ПАС под ред. Лопатина, § 54 (примечание) http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119

2. Выражение "партия **количеством** менее 10 посылок" корректно с точки зрения грамматики. Сравнить: крошки **размером** с конопляное зерно.

Answer (score 0):

Если кратко — нет, запятые не нужны.

Не могу сослаться на правила, но поскольку в части `количеством менее 10 посылок` нет ничего, делающего ее самостоятельной частью сложного предложения или оборотом, требующим выделения запятыми, можно попробовать заменить ее одним словом, схожим по смыслу. Например, `маленькой`. Получается:

> Дополнительная плата за сбор партии(,) маленькой(,) не взимается.

Порядок слов получился неверный, но здесь это не имеет значения. Можно его исправить, смысл не изменится. Теперь рассмотрим два варианта:

> 1. Дополнительная плата за сбор маленькой партии не взимается.
> 2. Дополнительная плата за сбор партии, маленькой, не взимается.

Первый вариант однозначно верный по смыслу. Во втором же `маленькой` — это уточнение: конкретно эта партия — маленькая, но влияет ли это на дополнительную плату — неизвестно. Смысл получается явно не тот, что вы хотели донести.

Вывод: запятые не нужны.